# Narrowing conversion differences

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

With both g++ and clang it's ok to compile

```
std::vector<int> xs{1, 2, 3u};
```

but it's not ok to compile

```
std::vector<int> xs{1, 2, 3.0};
```

What is the rationale behind this apparently bizarre choice?

If we consider the **type** of the last value both `unsigned` and `double` cannot be converted safely to an `int`, and if we consider instead **the specific literal values** both `3u` and `3.0` can instead be converted safely.

Why the distinction then?

The formal specification says that the conversion is allowed from ints or enums to a different it if the value can be represented and even allows conversions from literals that lose data (for example `double` to `float`). Funnily enough this leads to:

```
 std::vector<float> x{1073741824};  // ok, value can be represented
 std::vector<float> y{1073741823};  // not ok, narrowing
 std::vector<float> z{1073741823.}; // ok (even if loses precision!)
 std::vector<int> w{3.0};           // not ok, just because
```

Answer (score 2):

Because [*list initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) can not do [*narrowing conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions).

Comment: Thanks for the links... however the question is why for the integers the specific value is considered (so it's safe from `3u` to `int`) but for floating point the value is not considered (so it's forbidden from `3.0` to `3`)?

Comment: @6502 In the second link (which links to the same page as the first), if you read the last point it explains why `3u` is allowed. If you tried `3000000000u` it would not have been allowed.

Comment: No. It says that it's allowed. Not **why** it is allowed and for floating point is not allowed. I found hard to explain the distinction except by "Because it is so. Just memorize and shut down logic reasoning.". A similar approach for floating point could accept `3.0` and refuse `3.14` instead.

Comment: @6502 for that you have to [read the specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf). If you seek any other rationale not explained in the specification, you have to talk to the authors of the specification as no one else will be able to say anything other than "that's how it is".

Comment: In that document the definition is at the end of page 235. For floating-point to floating-point conversion C++ even allows losing precision (e.g. from `0.1` to `0.1f`), but exact conversions from double to integers (e.g. `3.0` to `3`) are not allowed. My first thought was about complexity of the implementation (esp. thinking to cross compilation) but given other checks that must be done this doesn't make sense (for example `int` to `float` is allowed, provided the specific value can be represented exactly: in other words `std::vector<float> x{1073741824};` is ok, but with `1073741823` is not).